# Test if Javascript Tic Tac Toe Game with mini max algorithm working correctly

Tags: javascript, module, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I have created a Tic Tac Toe Game that allows the user to play against the computer. The computer is supposed to implement the mini max algorithm where it chooses the best move to make in relation to the human user, whether it be to prevent the player from winning, or winning itself. The problem is, I can't tell if the program is working correctly as sometimes it appears to work and other times it doesn't. The code snippet below is the mini max function that I added to my code. Here is the link to the full code https://github.com/1reemy/tictactoe.

```js
    const minimax = (newBoard, user) => {
        let legitMove = emptySquares();
        let moves = [];
        const gameWinner = (user) => {
            let win = winner.find((combo)=>combo.every((idx) => sector[idx].textContent === user));
            if(user === player.humanPlayer){
                win;
            }else if(user === player.machine()){
                win;
            }else if(boardFull()){
                return;
            }
            return user;
         };
        if(gameWinner(player.humanPlayer)){
            return {score:-10};
        }else if(gameWinner(player.machine())){
            return {score:10};
        }
        for(let i = 0; i < legitMove.length; i++){       
          let move = {};
          move.index = newBoard[legitMove[i]];
          newBoard[legitMove[i]] = user;
          if(user === player.machine()){
          let result = minimax(newBoard,player.humanPlayer);
          move.score = result.score;
          }
          else{
              let result = minimax(newBoard, player.machine());
          move.score = result.score;
              }
          newBoard[legitMove[i]] = move.index;
          moves.push(move);
        }
        let bestMove;
        if(user === player.machine()){
          let bestScore = -10000;
          for(let i = 0; i < moves.length; i++){
          if(moves[i].score > bestScore){
            bestScore = moves[i].score;
            bestMove = i;
          }
          }
        }
        else{
          let bestScore = 10000;
          for(let i = 0; i < moves.length; i++){
          if(moves[i].score < bestScore){
             bestScore = moves[i].score;
             bestMove = i;
          }
          }
        }
        return moves[bestMove];
      }
```

Comment: "Can someone please review my code and let me know if it is working correctly.". With respect, no-one is going to do that. There is far too much code here for anyone not directly involved in it to want to analyse. Why don't *you* test it to decide if it's working as intended or not, and if not, describe to us exactly what the problem is and give us the minimum code necessary to recreate it. (Which hopefully is a lot less than this full code!)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @RobinZigmond. I have taken your advice and have narrowed down the issue to the specific code snippet that I am unsure about. I have also added the link to the code as reference.

Comment: If it "sometimes work and sometimes doesn't" it means it doesn't work as intended right? I don't get the question, it needs to be narrowed down more. An advice would be to look at the definition of minimax and create it from there, or look at some tutorial to get some idea.